# JQuery validation only works for the first element in the form submitted. [intend to validate all]

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

> The JQuery validation only works for the first element in the form submitted, Validation won't check
>    for the 2nd one. Need to find out what is missing. Swap the input for text1 and date2, validation still
>    works for the first one.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>
</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-multifile-plugin.googlecode.com/svn-history/r16/trunk/jquery.MetaData.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validate();

        $(".date").datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            minDate: new Date('1990/01/01'),
            maxDate: '30Y'
        });
    });
    function test() {
        alert(document.getElementById("datetext").getAttribute("must"));
    }        
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
           Text:<font color="red">* </font><input id="Text1" class="lvl {required:true,messages:{required:'blank not allowed.'}}"  /><br />
            Select Date2:<font color="red">* </font><input id="date2"  class="date {required:true,messages:{required:'Required:Need to enter 2 date.'}}" readonly="true" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 34):

Be sure to include a `name` attribute to your inputs.  I believe it uses the `name` attribute to build its list of validation fields and since you haven't specified a `name` attribute, jquery validation thinks the second field is the same name as the first.

For example, `<input id="Text1" name="Text1" />`

Comment: Thanks, had this issue and we were stumped, no idea though why it doesn't just use the element instead of the name field.

Comment: You have no idea how relieved I am by finding this post. I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why my validation routine doesn't work properly and highlights only the first invalid element. the official jquery validation docs are crap, had no idea the issue would be resolved easily by including a name attr, lmao.